# Preferred way of logging in nodejs deployed to Azure App Services

Tags: node.js, azure

I have created nodejs Web API, hosted as Azure App Service.

What would be the best way to log errors/info/debug/warning?

Comment: try bunyan or morgan.

Comment: Yes, bunyan is great, we are using it with LogzIO (ELK), but where to send these data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're using [Azure Log Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/log-analytics/) with some custom node-winston middleware that sends an async request out to the ALA REST service.  However, there is a bit of a lag between the event being sent from our node Web App and it appearing in the ALA dashboard so although it will be good for monitoring a production environment it's not great for rapid debugging or testing.

If you just write to console.log then everything does get stored in a log file that you can access through the Kudu console.  Kudu also has the ability to do a live tail of the console, as does the azure command line interface.  Because of this we're debugging using those and leaving ALA for the future.

Once we figure out what the pattern is for those logs being written (i.e. filename/size/time/etc.) we'll drop a scheduled Azure Function in to regularly archive those logs into cold blob storage.

I'll also add that according to the [Twelve Factor App](https://12factor.net/) in XI they recommend writing logs to stdout, which is what console.log does.  I always take these opinionated frameworks/methodologies as guidance and not strict rules, but at these seem to be grounded in reality and will at the very least spawn some interesting discussions among your team.

Comment: Were you able to do any batching or is it one http request to ala per log trace?

Comment: Last time I checked it was still one request per log trace.  We put the ALA project on hold.

Comment: I would agree that just using console.log is a good enough solution for general purposes.

Comment: And what about Azure Monitor Logs (Azure Monitor)? Does it fit the application level logging?

Answer (score 1):

As you're using Azure, I would recommend the Application Insights:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-nodejs

Comment: Great tool, but am I missing something in that it doesn't seem to take custom log messages?  It seems to be more focused on everything outside the node process and not receiving messages from inside.

Comment: did you check the Agent API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics ?

Comment: I did, and it seems to be more oriented towards state and metrics values than capturing traditional logging events.  They even state "It is recommended to aggregate metrics before sending them from your app, to reduce bandwidth, cost and to improve performance." which is opposite to what the OP wants to do.

Comment: Application Insights does not fit to log on the application level.